Too many authentication failures
Do you guys have any idea how I can resolve this issue?
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 50.88.2.46 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 50.88.2.46 port 22

I tried changing the MaxAuthTries, did not work, and the password authentication has never worked for me. I do not know what I am doing wrong!

This question is similar to: Too many authentication fails Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is the same problem, I have two different VPS which I have been trying to access them via SSH with no success, the password authentication has never worked for me, the error message is Permission denied, publickey, password.
So I have been trying to access both of them via SSH publickey, and I do not know what I am missing, but I have not been able to access any of them via SSH publickey either.
I am focused on one of them now, the one I posted the question in here.
